# Bases of subspaces.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I don't understand how can we prove this.

Find a basis of the following subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^4$:

a. The vectors $x = (x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4)$ where $x_1=2x_4$

b. The vectors for which $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 = 0$ and $x_3 + x_4 = 0$

c. The space which is generated from the vectors $\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1&1&1\end{pmatrix}^T$, $\begin{pmatrix}1 & 2&3&4\end{pmatrix}^T$, $\begin{pmatrix}2 & 3&4&5\end{pmatrix}^T$

I struggle with this exercise. Can you help me understand better? I know that for a group of vectors to be a basis of a subspace they must be linear independent.

Bonus: If $x_1, x_2$ are the solutions of $Ax = b$, is $x = x_1/3 + 2x_2/3$ a solution of $Ax=b$ as well?

For this I said that since $x$ can be written as a linear combination of $x_1, x_2$ then it belongs in the space of the solutions of $Ax=b$ and thus can be a solution of the system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For part A, $x_1$ and $x_4$ are obviously not linearly independent.  Therefore, a basis for $V = \text{Span}(x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4)$ cannot include both $x_1$ and $x_4$.  So long as $x_1, x_2$, and $x_3$ are linearly independent, then they will form a basis for $V$.

You can construct a similar argument for part B.  Can you figure out which vectors can be expressed as linear combinations of the others?  Remember, your goal is to specifically exclude linearly dependent vectors from your basis.  As in part A, it looks like once you've eliminated vectors that are definitely linearly dependent, then you'll have to assume that what remains is linearly independent.

For part C, a cool trick is to plug the vectors in as the rows of a matrix.  Then perform Gaussian elimination on that matrix.  The nonzero rows in the row-reduced matrix will form a basis for the row space of the original matrix.  That is, the nonzero rows will form a basis of $V = \text{Span}(x_1, x_2, x_3)$.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean in the first paragraph. If $x_1$ and $x_4$ are linearly dependent then $(x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4)$ can't be a basis of $R^4$ because each of these can't be written as a linear combination of each other right?

Comment: @user3601507, you're certainly right.  $x_1$ and $x_4$ are dependent, so $\{x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4\}$ cannot be a basis.  However, $\{x_1, x_2, x_3\}$ might be, assuming that $x_1, x_2$, and $x_3$ are linearly independent.

Comment: Oh I thought that in order for a vector to be a basis of a subspace it had to have the same number of elements as the vector space. In this case, four.

Comment: Nope.  For example, you can have a collection of $6$ vectors.  If all of them lie along the same line, however, then just one of them will form a basis for the subspace all $6$ span.